# Documentation for all possible Visual Studio keyboard commands

Tags: visual-studio

[The options window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhpzL.png)

I am interested in finding explanation for this entire list here.

All the searching on the Internet gets me to the popular commands, I want to see what all of them do.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for microsoft visual studio documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022